# ¿Como se hace un metodo que compare strings y devuelva el mayor?

Tags: c#

Me gustaría crear un metodo que compare strings sin la necesidad de funciones prediseñadas de .NET. Tiene que ser un tipo de comparación caracter a caracter del string

Mi idea es descifrar la palabra más corta y compararla letra por letra con el otro array de palabra (palabra2), para así ordenarlas alfabeticamente

Este es mi codigo

```
var mayor = 0;
        int n1 = arreglo[mayor].Length; //se le asigna a n1 lo que  hay en el espacio 0
        int n2 = arreglo[1].Length; //se le asigna el arreglo 1 

        if (n2 > n1)
        {
            var palabra = arreglo[mayor];
            string[] palabra1 = palabra.Split();
            for (var i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            {
                
            }
               
        }
        else 
            if (n2 < n1)
        {
            var palabra = arreglo[1];
            string[] palabra2 = palabra.Split();
            for (var i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            {

            }
              
        }
     
        return mayor;
    }
```

Aún no está terminado, pero no sé como proceder con el procedimiento

Me gustaría comparar esas dos cadenas sin necesidad del string compare

Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Debes  agregar que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar un array de string lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
string[] strArray = { "D", "C", "B", "A" }
Array.Sort(strArray);
//Resultado ABCD
```

Para recorrer el string podrias convertir cada string en un Array y recorrerlo con un for

```
// string array
string[] strArray = String.Join(" ", texto);
// char array
char[] charArray = texto.ToCharArray();

//loop con for
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
{
   string s = strArray[i];
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// Loop con for al reves
for (int i = strArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   string s = strArray[i];
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Y para ordernar el string podrias usar linq

```
string texto = "edcba"
String.Concat(texto.OrderBy(c => c))

//resultado = abcde
```

O hacer un metodo como este

```
public string SortString(string texto)
{
    char[] charArray = texto.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(charArray );
    return new string(charArray );
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Él se refiere a ordenar un arreglo de string (`string[]`), no los caracteres de una cadena (`char[]`).

Comment: le voy a dejar la opcion para string[], le agregue el resto por que me parece que podria facilitarle la vida pero voy a modificar la respuesta.